# Chrome dev tools replacing AJAX request with redirect

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-chrome-devtools, http-status-code-302

I've got an app that makes an AJAX call using jQuery. Upon error, in `Application_Error`, there's a `Response.Redirect` which sends you to an error page (it's designed for regular page errors, but it fires on failed AJAX requests as well).

In my real project, when I make this AJAX request, the Network tab of the Chrome dev tools shows the original request and URL for a split second, and when the error occurs, that line goes away and gets replaced by the request to `GenericError.aspx`. In reality, the original call received a 302, and there was a second call to `GenericError.aspx` - this is confirmed with Fiddler.

I tried to recreate with new small projects, and those always show properly, with both the 302 and the error page showing up as separate lines.

The "Preserve Log" checkbox is checked, but they both behave the same if unchecked as well.

The AJAX requests and 302 responses are practically identical between my real project and the small one, so I don't see why Chrome would treat them differently.

Are there any config options or anything I might be missing that could change the way Chrome dev tools would treat AJAX responses with 302 redirects?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. Did you find a way to see the request in Chrome?

Comment: I haven't tried in awhile - I doubt they've fixed it by now, but it's possible. I never found a workaround myself.